# Understanding the need for struts 2 and commons chain in simple CRUD website

Tags: java, design-patterns, web-applications, struts2, chain-of-responsibility

I have a simple CRUD website in development process, almost done. I was asked to refactor the code but this time use **struts 2** and **commons chain**. I read a couple of sites like [this](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts-2-features.shtml) but wasn't able to know exactly what will be the key roles done by these two (struts 2 and commons chain) in my project. I was also asked that don't worry about struts tags like in [this](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-validation-example-1.html) tutorial as the code that i made earlier can be used.

Can anyone give me an insight. Thanks

Note: A day back I started to see about **struts 2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well any framework is designed (most of them) to provide some sort of ease of use. That should be the driver when you chose one.

In your case, I can comment on **Struts2**.
Using Struts2 provides and enforces a better design in terms of separation of your code responsibilities (model view controller). This way the over all application design is well formed.
On top of this, framework provides many **interesting features** like interceptors, out of box request parameter assignments, validation, ui tags etc etc which you can benefit from.

So if you are still in the starting phase, yes - go through various frameworks available and weigh them out in terms of what ease you are looking for.

Comment: Can you suggest someplace to start, some link might be helpful, where I can get a basic struts2 app running in my system. In the mean time I am looking out too. Thanks

Comment: @Abhishek: Use the official struts 2 site, Manning Struts 2 is also very good. Some interesting short tuts are also listed on http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-tutorial/struts-2-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

If the website is almost done, I don't see any compelling reason to adapt Struts 2. In fact, the person who asked you all this is the best person to contact, in this case.

Regarding [commons chain](http://commons.apache.org/chain/), yes it can help you implement [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern if it can solve the cases in hand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to have a basic role idea about struts2 in a general CRUD application. Such that when i discuss it with my senior i have some basic idea about what he is saying and i am not totally lost :p